Pushout of Affine Schemes along Closed Subscheme: Toy Example
I trying to imagine how a toy example for a pushout in category of schemes should "typically" look like. In general their existence in not granted in category of schemes, but only as algebraic spaces (compare eg with discussion here).
I would like to inderstand by means of a 'toy example' how actually think about these. Let consider following case $X = \Bbb A^n_k$, for $k =\bar{k}$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ for $R$ local Artin $k$-algebra, and $Z=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ with canonical residue maps $Z \to Y, Z \to X$, idenify in latter map $k$ with residue field of point\prime $(0,0,...,0) \in \Bbb A^n_k$.
How intuitively think of the schematic pushout $Y \cup_Z X$ (by construction by Ferrand's result its existense as scheme is garanteed)?
Topologically I guess nothing interesting happen as is seems to be homeomorphic  to $X = \Bbb A^n_k$, but on level of structure sheaf - more precisely in local ring where $(0,...,0)$ gets "identified" with $Y$ there seemingly something intersting happen.
Recalling category theoretical definition of fibre products in category of rings I expect that the local ring at this point should formally be given as
$$ R\times_{k} \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^n,(0,...,0)}:=\{(a,b) \in R\times \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^n,(0,...,0)} \mid res(a)= res(b)\} $$
with resp to residue maps to residue fields.
Is it correct that the stalk at "glueing point" at first formally looks like this?
If yes, which general ring theoretical properties does it have resp. inherit from the both local ring from which it got constructed.
I was rather surprised that seemingly analysis of rings constructed in that way not discussed in usual "standard" books on commutative algebra. Does anybody know where I can find discussion about this ring/ rings constructed that way?
Obviosly, it's local (take inverse image of $0$ under residue map), but I not fully understand it's central feautures of its algebraic structure.
Surficially, this seems to be a kind of "fuzzification" of reduced ring $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^n,(0,...,0)}$.Can one sum up main features of this local ring?

Please have a look at Karl Schwede's paper on gluing schemes. Notice that $Z \to X$ is a closed immersion so the results apply. Maybe all your questions then answer themselves.

@Martin Brandenburg: Thanks, you mean that one mentioned in Greg Stevenson's post in linked thread? Unfortunately the link is dead, do you know the name of the paper?

"Gluing schemes and a scheme without closed points". It is online.
